# Blocking Disk Utility?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I'm looking for a way to prevent someone from creating a new partition on my hard drive in order to get around restrictions I've set. I've already tried setting an administrator account to no luck. The restrictions ended up blocking the systems I already have in place to prevent certain things, reopening holes I've already filled.

I've found a way to restrict third-party applications that create new partitions but Disk Utility is still accessible. I want to prevent someone else from using it, but I don't want to completely block it. I'd like to let him use it under supervision if needed and use it myself. The fact that Mac OS's restrictions kind of mess everything up makes this a challenge.

Perhaps there's a third party application that allows someone to prevent applications from launching without a password? Not being able to uninstall it without a password would be a requirement as well. Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to fix this problem?

Comment: Can't you just make the other user a normal one without administration rights?

Comment: Ordinarily yes, but not without it trying to block other applications that prevent him from doing other things. Mac OS's restrictions are dumb like that. I've tried both everything I could think of and everything recommended to me. It won't work in this case.

Comment: Can you explain more about what it prevents working? This looks like an XY-problem, where the better solution would be for him to have a non-admin, and then just let that problematic application run with administrator-privileges.